# Derive the formula that from x and y generates z

Tags: r, algorithm, math, formula

I need to obtain the math formula that with 2 variables (like *x* and *y*) generates an outcome *z*.
I have no information about the type of formula, but I have many examples of *x*, *y* and *z* values.
There is in R a package with a function that can do this?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is a supervised machine learning problem and there is punch of algorithms to deal with , try this if it help [Optimization in R](https://www.is.uni-freiburg.de/resources/computational-economics/5_OptimizationR.pdf)

Comment: Consult a statistician or data scientist. Your main issue is not a programming issue and you don't appear to be qualified.

Answer (score 0):

Not a formula, but an interpolation is possible. With the **akima** package, and you can plot with **graph3d** or **plotly**.

```r
library(akima)

set.seed(666)
Grid <- expand.grid(x = 1:4, y = 1:4)
x <- Grid$x
y <- Grid$y
z <- rpois(16, 100)

itrp <- interp(x, y, z, linear = FALSE, extrap = TRUE)

outputGrid <- expand.grid(x = itrp$x, y = itrp$y)
dat <- data.frame(x = outputGrid$x, y = outputGrid$y, z = c(itrp$z))
dat <- subset(dat, !is.na(z))

library(graph3d)
graph3d(dat, keepAspectRatio = FALSE, verticalRatio = 1)
```

[image]